# WordPress Install issue

Tags: wordpress

New WP install. Getting this error...

Unpacking the package…

Could not extract file from archive. civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/themes/dark/img/files/big/..png

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: I just downloaded/extracted the file and didn't see that error.  Could you edit your question to indicate which version you downloaded and where you downloaded it from?